# How to put array to function If I want to write to it in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Hi I tried to google but still I am confused a lot about the array in C. What I need is to create an array in main function and then use it in some other function. But I need to write to the array something and I need to have the written information there when I go away from the function, I need to work again with the array... So how to properrly write the code?

```
main(){
  int *matrix;
  matrix=calloc(10,sizeof(int));
  function(matrix? &matrix?)
  printf("%d",array[1]);
}

void function (*array? **array?){
   array[1]=5;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t have any arrays, only block of memory. And ”int *” is the correct type for your parameter.

Comment: Once it is a dynamically created block of memory it's not called as array? ok, and to the function I have to write &matrix? or matrix?

Comment: correct it’s not an array if you use malloc, the array type ”int [10]” and ”int*” are different.

Comment: For the funtiom only ”array” is sufficent, because the array variable is of type ”int*”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that modifies your code so that it allocates some memory and passes a pointer to it as a parameter to a function that writes a value to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int *array) {
    array[1] = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *matrix;
    const int length = 10;
    matrix = calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    if (NULL == matrix) {
        perror("Could not allocate memory for matrix");
        exit(1);
    }
    function(matrix);
    printf("%d\n", matrix[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes thatnk, but now what if I need to realloc the array in the function? That' not working for me :/

Comment: @MartinIndrych: "*I need to realloc the array in the function*" That's worth another question.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you want something like this..

```
int main(void) {
    int matrix[] = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    matrix[] = function(matrix[]);
    printf("%d", matrix[1]);
}

int function(int array[]) {
.
.
.
    return array[];
}
```

I am not quite sure on specifics but you can go [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) to check out more. If the jargon on the websites is what is confusing I would look up definitions so that the code is easier to understand.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Did you test this code? Does it compile using a C compiler?